# Configure Social login for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I used social login plugin on wordpress by oneall but cannot customize how the icons look in CSS. Is there a work around this issue if your trying to customize your icons?

Comment: Social login is a form of single sign-on using existing information from a social networking service such as Facebook, Twitter or Google+, to sign into a third party website instead of creating a new login account specifically for that website.

Comment: Have you considered using https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/ ?

Comment: Have researched that and trying it out. Is it reliable enough to be used!